# How to add a license file in git

Tags: git

How to add a license file to a git project which is not hosted on GitHub? I want to use license templates to create my one like GitHub.

Is it possible to create a license file, not creating it manually, in git?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A license file is just a file.... for git, it's business as usual, just add it and commit

Answer (score 2):

> How to add a license file to a git project which is not hosted on GitHub? I want to use license templates to create my one like GitHub.

You can create any file you wish and add it to any git repository.
Github supply pre-made templates.

Use this site to choose your license:

#### **https://choosealicense.com/**

This site will supply you with the content of your license.
Choose your license and copy it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To add to other answers, there are tools to generate the `LICENSE` files for you:

1. [generate/generate-license](https://github.com/generate/generate-license) (Javascript, npm): has a fancy interactive CUI for license selection. Supports more licenses by working with the list from [choosealicense.com](https://choosealicense.com/) (like Github!)
2. [azu/license-generator](https://github.com/azu/license-generator) (Rust, cargo): very simple CLI, picks up current git credentials. Fewer licenses included.
   Example: `license-generator mit`